# Password recovery for Microsoft Word 2007 documents

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, password-recovery

I have forgotten the password of my protected Microsoft Word 2007 document, is there any way to crack it?

Comment: Belongs to Super User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are a variety of applications which will help you reset and/or recover the password.

Here are just a few:

1. http://www.petri.co.il/uri/bww/office-password/download
2. http://lastbit.com/word/default.asp
3. Google Search:  http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=Word+password+recovery+&aq=f&aqi=g4g-o1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=cc7ad1a43d378bba

Hope that helps